# Drop first two and last column in multiple CSV files in same directory

Tags: python, shell, csv

I'm wondering what would be the best approach to remove first two and last column from multiple CSV files that have the same column structure.

I've tried with awk and pandas but it seems that it gives me only an option to remove columns from one input.csv file at the time and save it as output.csv. How could I remove columns 1,2,7 in multiple files without creating output.csv but overwriting existing files?

My CSV files look like this, where Col1, Col2, Col7 are completely empty (including column header).

```
Col1,Col2,  Col3   ,  Col4   ,  Col5   ,   Col6  ,Col7
    ,    ,some_data,some_data,some_data,some_data,
    ,    ,some_data,some_data,some_data,some_data,
    ,    ,some_data,some_data,some_data,some_data,
```

and desired output:

```
  Col3   ,  Col4   ,  Col5   ,   Col6
some_data,some_data,some_data,some_data
some_data,some_data,some_data,some_data
some_data,some_data,some_data,some_data
```

My code so far...

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import fileinput
from dateutil import parser
# specifying directory and determining files for my loop 
path = r'/path/to/my/files'
files = [os.path.join(path,data_file) for data_file in sorted(os.listdir(path))]
#trying to read each csv file separately and delete columns from it
df = pd.read_csv(files)
# specifying columns to delete
first_column = df.columns[0]
second_column = df.columns[1]
last_column = df.columns[7]
# Delete my columns
df = df.drop([first_column, second_column, last_column], axis=1)
# trying to overwrite existing files after column removal instead of creating new files i.e. output.csv
df.to_csv(files, index=False)
```

Comment: Can you post a precise example (ideally simplest possible example in code)? Pandas is perfect for this problem, in my experience

Comment: Hi @Mark, added my code above. It's simple for a single file, but I encountered loads of difficulties in applying column deletion to multiple files.

Comment: You need to loop through all the files in the directory (using `os.listdir(<path>)` to create a list), applying this code to each file

Comment: thanks for pointing me to os.listdir Mark! However, I have issues merging it with my previous code (see above). It throws first error at this line "df = pd.read_csv(files)". Would you be able to help or suggest something?

Comment: @Baobab1988, why don't you show a chunk of the input file and of the corresponding desired output?

Comment: I'd look into `csvcut` from the `csvkit` package.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis just added how my CSV files look above. And Shawn, would you be able to tell how csvcut would be able to tackle multiple files in directory at the same time?

Comment: @Baobab1988, the example you presented is _already_ a 4 column file, except that it has more headers than necessary. You can go from input to output by only changing the header line.

Comment: @Baobab1988, what does _where Col1, Col2, Col7 are completely empty (including column header)_ mean? You have put those headers in the input file. Those header are the only difference between the input and output files.

Comment: When i open my files in plain text editor then I see two extra commas at the beginning and one at the end of each row. Should I then focus on removing those values instead of aiming to remove columns in my csv files?

Comment: @Baobab1988, then where are the commas in the question? Can you please _show a chunk of the input file and of the corresponding desired output_, and not your without-commas interpretation of it? The chunk need not be from the actual file, ok, but it needs to be representative of it. You first wrote about a CSV file, then you post an example of input/output where there's no comma. This does not help readers.

Comment: Multiple files? With a loop, of course.

Comment: @Shawn, no need for a loop: `find . -type f -exec sed/awk/bash_script {} \;` would be enough.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis There's enough steps (Save processed file in a temporary; overwrite original with that) that it's easier with a shell for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not creating a temporary file is not a strinct requirement ([your self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60021890/5825294) creates new files indeed), this is oneliner.

```
find /path/to/your/dir -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c 'cut -d, -f3-6 $0 > $0.new && mv $0.new $0' {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /path/to/my/file

for file in *.csv
do
cut -d, -f3,4,5,6,7 "$file" > "new_$file"
done
```

this actually did the job.

Comment: Your own answer is wrong. Indeed this solution will keep the last comma because you are are taking columns from 3 to 7, whereas you explicitly stated that you wanted to remove columns 1,2, and 7. Besides, you are creating a new file, whereas in your question you explicitly wrote _without creating output.csv but overwriting existing files_.